# How to sum width of list items has top equal to 0px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<ul class="listul">
    <li style="width:10px; top: 0px"></li>
    <li style="width:10px; top: 0px"></li>
    <li style="width:10px; top: 5643px"></li>
    <li style="width:10px; top: 56px"></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var top = $('.listul li').css('top');
var wT = 0;
if (top = '0px'){
    $(this).each(function(){
        wT += $(this).outerWidth();
    });
    alert(wT);
}
```

I want to sum width of li with if(top = '0px') but
This is not work, please help me

Answer (score 1):

To loop each list item and check `top` value, you should try:

```
$(function(){

    var wT = 0;
    var items = $('.listul li');
    items.each(function(){
        if($(this).css('top') == "0px"){
             wT += $(this).outerWidth();
        } 
    });
    alert(wT);

});
```

**See** [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JcvHr/)

Answer (score 0):

specify width:10px in style tag for li. not width10px

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var wT = 0;
$('.listul li').each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    if ($element.css('top')=='0px') {
        wT+=$element.outerWidth();
    }
});

alert(wT);
```

Here is the **DEMO**: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MmanF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

your html code has to be like this :

```
 <ul clas="listul">
    <li style="width: 10px; top: 0px;"></li>
    <li style="width: 10px; top: 0px;"></li>
    <li style="width: 10px; top: 5643px;"></li>
    <li style="width: 10px; top: 56px;"></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this will help u.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using compare operator (==) in your if statement.